Click is not being executed at end_time
So I have a Python script which I have been working on for some time and I am coming across a small issue and I can't seem to figure it out.

So for a small debrief, this basically what the functionality needs to be:

Click on the Spirit Attraction Potion 1 (Dose 1).
Set the end time for 15 minutes later.
Click on the Seren Stones in a random sequence within the 15 minutes.
After 15 minutes, stop clicking Seren Stones and click on the next dose of the potion.
Repeat until all doses of the potion are used.
Move to the next potion and repeat the process.


So here are the logs that are produced:
07:59:19 - Initial delay of 10 seconds before first click.
07:59:29 - Clicked on Spirit Attraction Potion 1 (Dose 1). Total clicks: 1
07:59:32 - Current time: 07:59:32, End time set to 08:14:32
07:59:32 - Clicked on Seren stone. Total clicks: 2
08:05:37 - Clicked on Seren stone. Total clicks: 3
08:11:52 - Clicked on Seren stone. Total clicks: 4
08:17:03 - 15 minutes interval completed for Potion 1, Dose 1.
08:17:04 - Clicked on Spirit Attraction Potion 1 (Dose 2). Total clicks: 5

Question:
As we can see, the end time was set at 08:14:32, which was 15 mins after 07:59:32, however for some reason, the 15 minute interval did not complete until 08:17:03, it should have completed at 08:14:32. I have tried everything and I can't seem to figure out what is wrong so I could use some assistance.
Here is the code:
import time
import random
import logging
import sys
import threading
import pyautogui
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode

# Setup logging to output to the console
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
    datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
    stream=sys.stdout
)

# Activation keys
START_STOP_KEY = KeyCode(char='-')
EXIT_KEY = KeyCode(char='+')

# Configuration
INITIAL_DELAY = 10  # Initial delay before the first click (seconds)
SEREN_CLICK_INTERVAL_MIN = 300  # Minimum interval between Seren stone clicks (seconds)
SEREN_CLICK_INTERVAL_MAX = 600  # Maximum interval between Seren stone clicks (seconds)
POST_CLICK_DELAY = 3  # Delay after each click (seconds)

# Global state
running = False
click_count = 0
click_thread = None
lock = threading.Lock()

def on_press(key):
    global running, click_thread
    try:
        if key == START_STOP_KEY:
            with lock:
                running = not running
            if running:
                logging.info("Script started.")
                click_thread = threading.Thread(target=click_loop)
                click_thread.start()
            else:
                logging.info("Script stopped.")
        elif key == EXIT_KEY:
            logging.info(f"Exiting script. Total clicks made: {click_count}")
            with lock:
                running = False
            if click_thread:
                click_thread.join()
            listener.stop()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error in on_press: {e}")

def click_loop():
    global click_count, running
    try:
        logging.info(f"Initial delay of {INITIAL_DELAY} seconds before first click.")
        time.sleep(INITIAL_DELAY)

        while running:
            try:
                perform_click_sequence()
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Error during click loop iteration: {e}")
                with lock:
                    running = False
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error in click_loop: {e}")
        with lock:
            running = False

def perform_click_sequence():
    global click_count
    try:
        # Define coordinate ranges for each potion (example ranges)
        potion_coordinate_ranges = [
            ((1560, 1576), (838, 860)),  # Potion 1 (Row 3)
            ((1602, 1622), (838, 860)),  # Potion 2 (Row 3)
            ((1645, 1664), (838, 860)),  # Potion 3 (Row 3)
            ((1686, 1708), (838, 860)),  # Potion 4 (Row 3)
            ((1560, 1576), (874, 896)),  # Potion 1 (Row 4)
            ((1602, 1622), (874, 896)),  # Potion 2 (Row 4)
            ((1645, 1664), (874, 896)),  # Potion 3 (Row 4)
            ((1686, 1708), (874, 896)),  # Potion 4 (Row 4)
            ((1560, 1576), (908, 930)),  # Potion 1 (Row 5)
            ((1602, 1622), (908, 930)),  # Potion 2 (Row 5)
            ((1645, 1664), (908, 930)),  # Potion 3 (Row 5)
            ((1686, 1708), (908, 930)),  # Potion 4 (Row 5)
            ((1560, 1576), (946, 968)),  # Potion 1 (Row 6)
            ((1602, 1622), (946, 968)),  # Potion 2 (Row 6)
            ((1645, 1664), (946, 968)),  # Potion 3 (Row 6)
            ((1686, 1708), (946, 968)),  # Potion 4 (Row 6)
            # ... add coordinate ranges for all 26 potions
        ]

        for potion_number in range(1, 16):  # Loop through 16 potions
            for dose in range(4):  # Each potion has 4 doses
                if not running:
                    logging.info("Script is not running. Exiting click sequence.")
                    return

                # Get the coordinate range for the current potion
                x_range, y_range = potion_coordinate_ranges[potion_number - 1]
                
                # Generate random coordinates within the specified range
                x = random.randint(x_range[0], x_range[1])
                y = random.randint(y_range[0], y_range[1])
                
                # Click on the current potion
                click(f"Clicked on Spirit Attraction Potion {potion_number} (Dose {dose + 1})", x, y)

                time.sleep(POST_CLICK_DELAY)
                
                # Calculate the end time for the 15-minute interval
                end_time = time.time() + 15 * 60
                logging.info(f"Current time: {time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time.time()))}, End time set to {time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.localtime(end_time))}")
                
                # Click Seren stones in a random sequence within the 15 minutes
                while time.time() < end_time:
                    if not running:
                        logging.info("Script is not running. Exiting click sequence.")
                        return
                    
                    click("Clicked on Seren stone", random.randint(780, 965), random.randint(335, 380))
                    
                    # Sleep for a random interval between clicks on Seren stone
                    time.sleep(random.uniform(SEREN_CLICK_INTERVAL_MIN, SEREN_CLICK_INTERVAL_MAX))
                    time.sleep(POST_CLICK_DELAY)

                logging.info(f"15 minutes interval completed for Potion {potion_number}, Dose {dose + 1}.")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error in perform_click_sequence: {e}")

def click(description, x, y):
    global click_count
    pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
    pyautogui.click()
    click_count += 1
    logging.info(f"{description}. Total clicks: {click_count}")

try:
    with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:  # Start the keyboard listener
        logging.info("Listener started. Press '-' to start/stop and '+' to exit.")
        listener.join()  # Wait for the listener to stop
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f"Error starting listener: {e}")

Thanks all!

After the fourth click, the random sleep interval happened to be long enough to exceed the end time.  Were you expecting the while loop to automatically break in that case?  That's not how while loops work.  Their condition is checked only at the top of the loop.  If the condition becomes false during the loop execution, the loop will continue to execute as normal, until the condition is checked on the next iteration.

@JohnGordon I was indeed looking at breaking it as soon as the end_time was over, interesting find that I did not see previously. Need to figure out how I can break it after end_time.

When a program calls sleep(), it can't do anything at all until the time has passed.  So before calling sleep, you probably need to check if the sleep time would exceed the limit, and if so, shorten the time.
